# How to redirect output to a file only if it exists?

Tags: bash

This is the opposite of the clobber / noclobber feature. I only want to update the file if it already exists. I know I can do it with multiple commands, but is there a single operator that does it?

Comment: `exec` will fail if all redirects to exec fail. What are you actually trying to accomplish and why can't you use noclobber or just test the proper way using an ordinary test expression? Normally a test expression *is* the right way to do it

Comment: yes, a test expression would work; i was looking for a shortcut such as the ">|" operator which is strictly not necessary but available as a convenience. i am trying to avoid a file being created and polluting a directory if the command is run from the wrong current working directory. as you say, i can get around this, so no big deal, but it would be nice to have an operator to avoid "clobbering" the wrong directory. i RTFM-ed and this question is now a feature request :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I RTFMed and the operator does not exist yet.

Answer (score 3):

Closest I can think of is `[[ -f "$filename" ]] && do something > "$filename"`

Comment: Thanks. I wish I could also accept it in addition to upvoting. But, unfortunately, the right answer is that the operator does not exist. Thanks for the compact syntax though, it deserves the upvotes.